# Insert Value, new line macro

Tags: vba, excel

I drafted two tables to calculate some values. One value (attractiveness) appears in H16, the other (competivity) in H26.

Each time I calculate new values, I must be able to add these into columns K and L, when pressing a ADD-button. Both of the columns have the following range; K10:K26 and L10:L26.

So the first time I press "add", I want H16 to be transferred to K10 and H26 to L10. The second time I press "add", I want the new values in H16 and H26 to be inserted in K11 and L11.

I've already several ways, but my basic knowledge is just apparently less than basic.

Comment: I've tried the recorder indeed, this was the result:

Sub InTable()
'
' InTable Macro
'

'
    Range("H16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("H26").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your workbook?

Comment: Is it alright that I do this tomorrow? It's a company file with secured access. I don't have access with my Macbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last used row in a column like this:

```
Columns(col_number).Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Assuming that K10 is the last used row you could do something like this:

```
Cells(Columns(11).Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 11).Value = Range("H16").Value
```

This would find the last used row + 1 and in column 11 (K) and set its value to the value of H16

Another way of doing this is to start at row 10 and just keep going down until you find a blank cell and set its value to whatever you want.

For eample:

```
'Create a variable to store the current row
Dim i As Long

'Start at row 10 and go down until you find a blank cell
For i = 10 To Rows.Count
    'If the current cell is blank
    If Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
        'Set its value to H16
        Cells(i, 11).Value = Range("H16").Value
        'Stop looking for blank cells
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```